# Unable to build existed app using Sencha cmd

Tags: ios, sencha-touch-2.1, build-error

I'm trying to build the existed Sencha based app using Sencha cmd. But the build is failed by displaying the following error messages. I tested the Sencha cmd by creating an example, the new app is working fine and built successfully but the problem is with the existed app.

```
Alens-Mac-mini:SenchaApp Projects$ sencha app build package
Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250
[INF]       init-properties:
[INF]       init-sencha-command:
[INF]       init:
[INF]       -before-app-build:
[INF]       app-build-impl:
[INF]       package:
[INF]       -before-init-local:
[INF]       -init-local:
[INF]       -after-init-local:
[INF]       init-local:   
[INF]       find-cmd:
[INF]       -before-init:
[INF]       -init:
[ERR]       BUILD FAILED
[ERR]       com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: Problem: failed to create task or type x-verify-app-cmd-ver
[ERR]       Cause: The name is undefined.
[ERR]       Action: Check the spelling.
[ERR]       Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
[ERR]       Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
[ERR]           at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.wrap(BasicException.java:43)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:104)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.dispatch(AbstractCommand.java:182)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.SenchaCommandTask.doExecute(SenchaCommandTask.java:58)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.BaseAntTask.execute(BaseAntTask.java:22)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERR]           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:72)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:87)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:91)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands    $BaseNamePathCommand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:135)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands    $BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:106)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERR]           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:71)
[ERR]       Caused by: /Users/Alens/Desktop/SenchaApp/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:91: Problem: failed to create task or type x-verify-app-cmd-ver
[ERR]       Cause: The name is undefined.
[ERR]       Action: Check the spelling.
[ERR]       Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
[ERR]       Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.getNotFoundException(UnknownElement.java:487)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:419)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ERR]           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:80)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.command.ant.AntCommand.execute(AntCommand.java:75)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERR]           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERR]           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERR]           at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]           ... 31 more
[ERR]       Total time: 3 seconds
[ERR]       com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: Problem: failed to create task or type x-    verify-app-cmd-ver
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Comment: Cause: The name is undefined.. Have you looked in this direction ?

Comment: The version of ST you're using and of Sencha CMD could also help.

Comment: Thank you so much TDeBailleul.... this solved my problem.... Sencha cmd of existed app and the Sencha cmd running in my Mac are different...this created the problem and upgrading my Sencha cmd to the existed app Sencha cmd solved my problem

Comment: Thank you very much. I too had the same problem. Then installed the correct version of the sencha cmd and it solved my problem too.. Thanks again...

Comment: Please find the more detail answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34339357/2935802