# Sencha build due to sass target

Tags: sass, compass, sencha-cmd

I am trying to build a Sencha app but I am getting the following errors:

> [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
> /Users/conor/Repositories/POS/pos/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:286:
>
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> /Users/conor/Repositories/POS/pos/.sencha/app/sass-impl.xml:280:
>
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> /Users/conor/Repositories/POS/pos/.sencha/app/sass-impl.xml:286:
>
> Problem: failed to create task or type x-compass-compile Cause: The
> name is undefined. Action: Check the spelling. Action: Check that any
> custom tasks/types have been declared. Action: Check that any
> / declarations have taken place.

I looked into the Ant scripts and it appears that the issue is around the SASS process using Compass.

I can confirm that Compass v1.0.3 is installed.

After that, I am not a Sencha expert so am stuck. How can I fix this issue please?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. While I did have this error, it turns out sencha was compiling my app successfully. I just needed to check the correct output folder and my application was there.

Comment: I am seeing this same error.  I am also new to Sencha and extjs.  I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.4, Sencha Cmd 6.0.0.202, Ruby 2.0.0.p481

Comment: @conor did u solve this issue

Comment: No, I just ignored the error as my application was successfully built prior to the error showing.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this error too. I had just upgraded to Sencha CMD 6.0.2.14. [Download page](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/cmd-download/)

It looks like you're using Sencha Touch and it's probably 2.x. There's a component called "Compass extension" in the installer that needs to be checked.

[image: See screenshot]

2. If you didn't install the ruby, Install the ruby2.X. Ruby is required to build the sencha application and set **'ruby' to your system path variable.**
   eg: check your ruby version with `ruby -v`

Comment: To clarify the comments above:
When installing Sencha Cmd, you need to tell the installer to install the "Compass Extension". This is generally done by checking the checkbox next to "Compass Extension".

Comment: how to install it in Linux env without GUI ?

Comment: Found it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227994/senchacmd-silent-install-with-compass-extension-component