# SenchaCMD - silent install with compass extension component

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, silent-installer

I want to install sencha silently (without GUI) or dialog boxes from my Linux terminal. How to add compass extension component to installation automatically? I've checked sencha help, and there is only "quit" option, but not something as "all". This is not helping to me (using -a -q while installing) https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303323-Installing-Sencha-CMD-6-silently-with-the-compass-extension
Also, how can I check if the compass extension has been installed? Thank you.

Comment: Why doesn't the Sencha thread work for you? Please elaborate.

Comment: While executing sencha app build, I am getting message: Problem: failed to create task or type x-compass-compile
Cause: The name is undefined.
When I add compass extension component in my installation, build is succesfull.

Answer (score 10):

It should be `-Dall=true` switch.

So the command should look like this:

```
/SenchaCmd-6.2.0-linux-amd64.sh -Dall=true -q -dir /opt/Sencha/Cmd/6.2.0
```